# C++ Multiple Inheritance: Using base class A's implementation for abstract method of base class B

Tags: c++, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, overriding

I have an abstract class `Interface` that declares `f()` and `g()` methods.

`MyClass` implements `Interface::g()`, and `MyClass` inherits from `Base`, which implements its own `f()`.

How can I make `Base::f()` be the implementation for `Interface::f()` in `MyClass`?

I don't want to make `Base` inherit from `Interface` directly, if possible.

```cpp
class Interface {
    public:
        virtual void f() = 0;
        virtual void g() = 0;
};

class Base {
    public:
        void f() { }
};

class MyClass : public Interface, public Base {
    public:
        void g() { }
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    c.f();
    c.g();
}
```

This doesn't work, because `f` is still a pure virtual function in `MyClass`.

In Java, I would use the following approach, but it obviously doesn't work in C++.

```java
public class MyClass extends Base implements Interface {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        c.f();
        c.g();
    }
    public void g() { }
}

class Base {
    public void f() { }
}

interface Interface {
    public void f();
    public void g();
}
```

The concrete problem I'm trying to tackle is the following:

The `Interface` in the example above is an abstract class `Sender` with different methods related to sending MIDI messages, e.g. `update()` (check if a message should be sent, and send it if necessary), and `setAddress()` to change the address of the message. The messages are MIDI events. I have to change the address/channel for functions like transposing and selecting different banks.

The `Base` class is a class `Button`. It has a method `update()` that checks whether the button is pressed or not, and calls the (virtual) methods `press()` and `release()` accordingly.

`MyClass` would then implement the `press()` and `release()` methods, to send the right data when the button state changes.

There are other types of `Sender`s as well, and I keep them all in a list to `update()` them all at once, regardless of the specific type of `Sender`. I also need to be able to change the address of all `Sender`s in the list (all at once).

The `setAddress()` method has nothing to do with a button, so it doesn't make sense to have `Button` inherit from `Sender`.
There are also other classes that would implement `Button`, but they are not all `Sender`s.

Maybe I have to change the structure entirely, but I don't really see a better solution at the moment.

```cpp
class Button {
    public:
        void update() {
            if ( /* check in hardware whether button is pressed */ )
                press();
        }
        virtual void press() = 0;
};

class Sender {
    public:
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual void setAddress(int address) = 0;
};

class ButtonSender : public Button, public Sender {
    public:
        void update() {
            Button::update();
        }
        void press() {
            /* send a message */
        }
        void setAddress(int address) {
            /* change the address */
        }
};

int main() {
    ButtonSender bs;
    Sender *s = &bs;
    s->update();
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what exactly does `Sender` class represent? If it is just a source of some event and the `Button` is such a source then it seems that `Button` indeed should inherit from `Sender`.

Comment: "_I don't want to make Base inherit from Interface directly, if possible._" but WHY? Please describe your question in term of problem you are trying to solve, not in term of possible C++ class hierarchies solving the problem.

Comment: @r3musn0x, I edited my question. There are Buttons that are not Senders, so I can't make Button inherit from Sender.

Comment: @r3musn0x, Sender represents an object that reads an input, and sends MIDI messages depending on the state of that input. In order to transpose a bank/group of Senders, the address must be changed.
It is meant for a microcontroller, the input that is updated is the state of a button, the position of a knob, the value of a sensor, etc. The Button class takes care of state change detection and software debouncing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, OP, for posting a more concrete example.  It has driven me to take the unusual step of posting a second answer.  I hope you find it useful.

What I'm going to do here is to show you an alternative class hierarchy which I hope you will see is better suited to the problem you want to solve.  I'm just going to focus on the relationship between class `Button` (which is where the fundamental problem lies) and something which I'm going to call a `ButtonHandler`.

Now a `ButtonHandler` could be anything - `Button` certainly doesn't care what it is - it just needs to be notified when *the button that it owns* is pressed or released.  Once you appreciate that that is at the heart of the problem, the solution becomes more obvious.  You can, of course, apply this approach to your `Sender` class (just derive it from `ButtonHandler` and implement `OnPress` and `OnRelease`), but I'll leave that bit to you.

Finally, as a bit of icing on the cake, I had my `Button`s add and remove themselves to / from that list you were talking about so that they can easily all be polled in some kind of loop.

OK, let's go.  Let's start with our `ButtonHandler` (since this needs to be declared before class `Button`), which is simple enough:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class Button;

// Our abstract button handler - derive concrete handlers from this
class ButtonHandler
{
public:
    // Constructor
    ButtonHandler ();

    // Destructor (must be virtual!)
    virtual ~ButtonHandler ();

    virtual void OnPress () = 0;
    virtual void OnRelease () = 0;

private:
    Button *m_button;
};
```

OK, not much to see there.  Note the pure virtual methods `OnPress` and `OnRelease` - which are there for concrete classes deriving from this one to override - and the forward declaration of class `Button`.  We will need to implement the constructor and destructor bodies later, after they have seen the full declaration of class `Button`, since they need to call methods on it.

Now for class `Button` itself, and the associated `ButtonList`.  Note that, again, because it deals only in *pointers* to `Button`s, `ButtonList` doesn't need to see the full declaration of class `Button`, which is kind of handy here:

```
std::set<Button *> ButtonList;

// class Button
class Button
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Button (ButtonHandler *button_handler)
    {
        m_button_handler = button_handler;
        ButtonList.insert (this);
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Button () { ButtonList.erase (this); }

    // Poll the button state
    void Poll ()
    {
        // This would normally check (in hardware) whether button is pressed, but here we just fake it
        m_button_handler->OnPress ();
        m_button_handler->OnRelease ();
    }

private:
    ButtonHandler *m_button_handler;
};

// Poll all the buttons that exist
void PollAllButtons ()
{
    for (auto button : ButtonList) { button->Poll (); }
}
```

So what's going on here?  Well:

- The `Button` constructor is passed a pointer to a `ButtonHander` so that it can call its `OnPress` and `OnRelease` methods when appropriate.
- The magic of the STL (when available!) makes implementation of `ButtonList` trivial.  It just uses a 
  `std::set`, which is documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (see examples on that page and linked pages).  Buttons add and remove themselves from this list as they come and go.
- `PollAllButtons` iterates through all the `Button *`s stored in `ButtonList` and calls what I chose to call `Poll` for each one, which in turn calls the associated `ButtonHandler`s `OnPress` and `OnRelease` methods as appropriate.  This uses something called a "ranged for loop", which works with, AFAIK, all the STL container classes.

Now the implementation of the `ButtonHandler` constructor and destructor.  These just create and delete the associated button (so, the `Buttonhandler` *owns* the button):

```
// ButtonHandler constructor - implementation
ButtonHandler::ButtonHandler ()
{
    m_button = new Button (this);
}

// Buttonhandler destructor - implementation
ButtonHandler::~ButtonHandler () { delete m_button; }
```

And finally, a concrete button handler and minimal test program that is included here to show you that all this stuff does actually work.  You will notice (and this is rather nice) that this is unchanged from the previous code I posted (which was [just that bit too clever](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rsNQzoE2AWgBEiWg)):

```
// An example concrete button handler
class MyButtonHandler : public ButtonHandler
{
public:
    // Constructor
    MyButtonHandler (int handler_id) { m_handler_id = handler_id; }

    void OnPress () override { std::cout << "MyButtonHandler::OnPress (" << m_handler_id << ")" << std::endl; }
    void OnRelease () override { std::cout << "MyButtonHandler::OnRelease (" << m_handler_id << ")" << std::endl; }
    // ...

private:
    int m_handler_id;
};

// Test program
int main ()
{
    MyButtonHandler bh1 (1);
    MyButtonHandler bh2 (2);
    PollAllButtons ();
}
```

Output:

```
MyButtonHandler::OnPress (1)
MyButtonHandler::OnRelease (1)
MyButtonHandler::OnPress (2)
MyButtonHandler::OnRelease (2)
```

Run it at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rsNQzoE2AWgBEiWg).

So there you go.  Very different to yours (because you set off on the wrong track and there was no way back from there).  I suggest you take it and run with it, best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed a clean solution to the problem, and it certainly helps my understanding. However, some of the microcontrollers I have to support (8-bit AVR) do not support the `functional` standard library (so no `std::bind` or `std::function`). This makes converting instance methods to functions (or function pointers) a whole lot harder. Is there a similar approach that I could follow, or is there a work-around without using `bind`? Again, thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: I will look into it.  Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Well, what do you know?  It's actually a lot simpler if you do it the old-fashioned way, serves me right for showing off.  I amended my post (and credited you with a bit more nous).  And lookee here: no multiple inheritance, woohoo!  Enjoy.

Comment: Of course, I could have summed all this up in one sentence: "A button handler _isn't_ a button, it _owns_ a button."  But where would the fun be in that?

Comment: But what if not all Senders are ButtonHandlers?

Comment: Make them so, number one.  Use multiple inheritance if you absolutely have to.  Of course, there are other ways, there always are.  Passing the address of a couple of _static_ member functions, plus your `this` pointer, to `Button`'s constructor (which would then of course have to be defined accordingly) would work, for example.  `Button` can then call these when it needs to and pass the handler's `this` pointer as an explicit parameter so that it can then call member functions on (or access member variables of) the handler itself.

Comment: This is arguably more flexible, if a bit less convenient.  Try coding it up as an exercise, ping me if you get into difficulties.

Comment: After trying to combine ButtonHandler and Senders, I decided to forget about the event handlers altogether, and just give button a getState method that returns an enum value (pressed, falling, released or rising), so nothing has to inherit from Button. ButtonSender just inherits from Sender, and it owns a Button. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To make this work you have to override `f()` in `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass : public Interface, public Base {
    public:
        void f() {
            Base::f();
        }
        void g() {
            cout << "MyClass::g()" << endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: I can live with the three extra lines, and this doesn't make `Base` inherit from `Interface` as in the solutions proposed by dbush and gsamaras. This answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have a function called `f` in both `Interface` and `Base` when you subsequently derive from both of them in `MyClass`?  You created a name clash right there, hence your difficulties.  Ok, so you can get away with it this time with  a three line method.  But next time?  And the next?  No, don't go there.

C++ is not Java - it doesn't *have* interfaces.  Instead, a concrete class (or chain of classes - using single inheritance) deriving from an abstract base class needs to implement *all* of the pure virtual methods declared by that class, as you have discovered.

What you are trying to do here goes against the spirit of the language and is likely to get you into trouble down the line so you need to adjust your thinking.

Multiple inheritance, especially when the same method or data member names are declared in one or more base classes, is usually a poor design choice and is symptomatic more often that not of errors inherent in the design of the class hierarchy in the first place so my recommendation is to revisit that - you'll be glad you did.

Anyway, now you know why you <strike>are</strike> were getting downvoted (although not by me).  I hope you find this useful - it is well intended.  I didn't have to write this but then again, I wanted to, I see this kind of thing a lot on SO and I find it painful.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. I edited my question to explain what it is that I actually want to do. I don't know how I should change my way of thinking, but maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: What about defining separate interfaces for `update()` and `setAddress()`?  For instance, you could have `IUpdatable` and `IAddressable`, then have `Button` derive from and implement `IUpdatable` only, and `Sender` derive from both `IUpdatable` and `IAddressable` without implementing them, then `ButtonSender` can derive from `Button` and `Sender` and implement `update()` and `setAddress()`. You might have to use virtual inheritance to address the two `IUpdatable` copies in `ButtonSender`, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that would indeed solve some of my problems, but then I wouldn't be able to call both the `setAddress()` function and the `update()` function on the same `Sender` pointer. I would like to keep a single list of Senders that I can change the address of, and that I can update all at once.

Comment: "*I wouldn't be able to call both the `setAddress()` function and the `update()` function on the same `Sender` pointer*"` - yes, you would, if `Sender` *derives* from **both** `IUpdatable` and `IAddressable`, thus having **both** `update()` and `setAddress()` available in its interface to callers, even if they are not *implemented* in `Sender` itself but in a descendant of `Sender` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Base` is implementing functions in `Interface`, so it should derive from that class.  Then `MyClass` only inherits from `Base`:

```
class Base : public Interface {
    public:
        void f() {
            cout << "Base::f()" << endl;
        }
};

class MyClass : public Base {
    public:
        void g() {
            cout << "MyClass::g()" << endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: I could use this approach for the simple example above, but the problem is that I can't have any classes inheriting from `Base` without having to implement all methods `g` from `Interface` as well, which I'd like to avoid. Is there any way around this, like the Java example?